Can anyone explain why this RSA calculation not working
I made a RSA encrypting and decrypting program.
Everything works well as it is suppose to be. However when I decrypt the message, it doesn't give me the message.
Can somebody check which part is wrong here?
    my message x = 18

    p = 4213
    q = 4217
    p and q are primes

    n = p* q = 17766221
    phi_n = 4212 * 4216 = 17757792
    -> (p - 1)(q - 1)

    e = 11
    e is relatively prime to phi_n

    d = inverse of e mod phi_n
      = inverse of 11 mod 17757792
      = 6457379

    encrypted_message = x^e (mod n)
                  = 18 ^ 11 (mod 17766221)
                  = 11689003

    decrypted_message = encrypted_message ^ d (mod n)
                  = 11689003 ^ 6457379 (mod 17766221)
                  = 5486335 (which is not 18)

I am very lost in this situation, I think all the values are good with RSA rules.
I am expecting the decrypted_message to be 18 but it is not.
Can somebody explain why RSA is not working is this calculations and how I should fix it?
Thank you.

Show us your actual code.  Pseudocode often does not have the same semantics.

4213 is not prime. It's divisible by 11.
